# ubuntu server pipeline stop process termination when the first exit

Tags: c++, linux, bash, pipeline

The situation is: I have an external application so I don't have the source code and i can't change it. While running, the application writes logs to the stderr. The task is to write a program that check the output of it and separate some part of the output to other file. My solution is to start the app like

```
./externalApp 2>&1 | myApp
```

the myApp is a c++ app with the following source:

```
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
string str;
ofstream A;
A.open("A.log");

ofstream B;
B.open("B.log");

A << "test start" << endl;

int i = 0;

while (getline(cin,str)) 
{
    if(str.find("asdasd") != string::npos)
    {
        A << str << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        B << str << endl;
    }
    ++i;
}

A << "test end: " << i << " lines" << endl;
A.close();
B.close();

return 0;
}
```

The externalApp can crash or be terminated. A that moment the myApp gets terminated too and it is don't write the last lines and don't close the files. The file can be 60Gb or larger so saving it and processing it after not a variant.

Correction: My problem is that when the externalApp crash it terminate myApp. That mean any code after while block will never run. So the question is: Is there a way to run myApp even after the externalApp closed?

How can I do this task correctly? I interesed in any other idea to do this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was not that when the first element of the pipe ended it terminate the second. The real problem was that the two app with pipes launched from bash script and when the bash script ended it terminated all of it child process. I solved it using

```
signal(SIGHUP,SIG_IGN);
```

that way my app executed to the end.
Thank you for all the answer at least I learned lot about the signals and pipes.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the shown code, and nothing in your question offers any evidence of anything being wrong with the shown code. No evidence was shown that your logging application actually received "the last lines" to be written from that external application. Most likely that external application simply failed to write them to standard output or error, before crashing.

The most likely explanation is that your external application checks if its standard output or error is connected to an interactive terminal; if so each line of its log message is followed by an explicit buffer flush. When the external application's standard output is a pipe, no such flushing takes place, so the log messages get buffered up, and are flushed only when the application's internal output buffer is full. This is a fairly common behavior. But because of that, when the external application crashes its last logged lines are lost forever. Because your logger never received them. Your logger can't do anything about log lines it never read.

In your situation, the only available option is to set up and connect a pseudo-tty device to the external application's standard output and error, making it think that's connected to an interactive terminal, while its output is actually captured by your application.

You can't do this from the shell. You need to write some code to set this up. You can start by [reading the pty(7) manual page](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman7/pty.7.html) which explains the procedure to follow, at which point you will end up with file descriptors that you can take, and attach to your external application.

Comment: I don't really need the last log lines i just want my logger to end correctly and exit with 0 and A and B.close();. My problem is that when the external app crash it terminate my app. That mean any code after while block will never run. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: I see no evidence that your app will terminate like that. It will properly terminate when `std::cin` is closed. You have not explained, or produced even one shred of evidence that documents your claim that your app terminates with a non-0 exit code, in this situation.

Comment: I made the decision about not proper termination of my program because i never ever saw those last "test end i lines" string at the end of my A.log file.
A << "test end: " << i << " lines" << endl;

Comment: I think i know what is the problem. All this executed using a bash script. The bash script has a stop function for the externalApp and when the bashscript exit it terminates all the child processes. I checked the parent process of myApp and it is the bash script. Any idea how to prevent the termination from myApp side?

Comment: Given the fact that you neglected to state the crucial fact that the termination messages from your logger weren't saved, but rather described the issue simply as the final log messages weren't getting logged, I see no reason to believe that this is an accurate description either and I should waste my time writing another answer. You need to visit stack overflow.com's Help Center and read the article on how to write a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program to cleanly deal with the external program crashing you will probably need to handle SIGPIPE.  The default behaviour of this signal is to terminate the process.

Comment: Sounds interesting I will google more about SIGPIPE then i will answer. Thanks

Comment: So i tryed to ignore the SIGPIPE signal but it does not helped me out. Maybe other signal terminate it because the SIGPIPE work when you try write on a pipe with no one to read it. In my case it is read only.

Comment: You get a SIGPIPE when you ***write*** to a pipe, not read from a pipe. Ignore this answer. It is utterly wrong.